# Flutter: reusable widget and BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

In a flutter app, let say I have this widget class with multiple widgets inside (ie. just a typical single long `Widget build()` class with multiple widgets inside). Then these are split into multiple children widgets, with their own classes: As an example,

Before:

```
 class Parents extend StatelessWidget{
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      //Parent
      return Column{
          children: <Widget>[
              //Child 1
              Container('something inside'),

              //Child 2
              Container('something inside'),

              //Child 3
              Container('something inside'),
              ...
          ]
      }
   }
 }
```

Now:

```
 class Parents extend StatelessWidget{
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      //Parent
      return Column{
          children: <Widget>[
              //Child 1
              myContainer('first child'),

              //Child 2
              myContainer('first child'),

              //Child 3
              myContainer('first child'),

              ...
          ]
      }
   }
 }

 class myContainer extend StatelessWidget{
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      //child reusable widget
      return Container{
        'something inside'
      }
   }
 }
```

The question that I have is this `Widget build(BuildContext context)`.

In the above example, I called the `myContainer` class three times in the parent class. In my mind, it means that the `build` widget is called four times (one with parent, 3 times from each child).

I mean, I saw a bunch of examples online that above approach is recommended, but is it really a proper way of doing it? I may not understand the flutter completely yet, but since it is a widget tree, would it be more efficient (in terms of performance wise) to simply pass the parent `context` down to the children? like below:

```
class myContainer extend StatelessWidget{
  final BuildContext parentContext;

   Widget build(parentContext){
      //child reusable widget
      return Container{
        'something inside'
      }
   }
 }
```

Both approaches seem to work but wanted to see if I am way off with my way of thinking. I don't fully understand the mechanism of `Context` and any clarification would be super appreciated!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html):

> Each widget has its own BuildContext, which becomes the parent of the
>   widget returned by the StatelessWidget.build or State.build function.
>   (And similarly, the parent of any children for RenderObjectWidgets.)
>
> In particular, this means that within a build method, the build
>   context of the widget of the build method is not the same as the build
>   context of the widgets returned by that build method. This can lead to
>   some tricky cases. For example, Theme.of(context) looks for the
>   nearest enclosing Theme of the given build context. If a build method
>   for a widget Q includes a Theme within its returned widget tree, and
>   attempts to use Theme.of passing its own context, the build method for
>   Q will not find that Theme object. It will instead find whatever Theme
>   was an ancestor to the widget Q. If the build context for a subpart of
>   the returned tree is needed, a Builder widget can be used: the build
>   context passed to the Builder.builder callback will be that of the
>   Builder itself.

So, this basically means that the `BuildContext` inside the `build()` method is actually that of it's parent. Hence, their is no need to explicitly pass it.

Comment: That was super helpful! Thanks! =)